# What is the most elegant way to apply multiple functions that mutates the same array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm trying to apply the same function to the same array with different parameters.
I can call the function with the different parameters one by one but it would be great to do it in a more elegant way. Like mapping over an array of parameters.

Currently this is my code.

```js
const array = [
  {
    key: '1234',
    title: 'Column 1'
  },
  {
    key: '5678',
    title: 'Column 2'
  },
  {
    key: '9101',
    title: 'Column 3'
  }
]

const renderFn1 = (props) => <Component1 {...props} />
const renderFn2 = (props) => <Component2 {...props} />

const addRender = (columns, key, fn) => {
  return columns.map(col => {
    if (col.key === key) {
      col.render = fn
    }
    return col
  })
}

const newColumns = addRender(columns, '1234', renderFn1)
const newColumns2 = addRender(newColumns, '9101', renderFn2)
```

Instead of this chain:

```js
const newColumns = addRender(columns, '1234', renderFn1)
const newColumns2 = addRender(newColumns, '9101', renderFn2)
```

How can I apply the right function to the right object in the array regarding the matching key.

Should I map over 2/3 array at the same time?

Thank you

Comment: "Most elegant" is a value judgement calling for an opinion, which is specifically off-topic for Stack Overflow. You might consider rephrasing.

Comment: Add function name to `const array` and then just loop your `array` with `columns = copy(array); for () {addRender(columns, arrayEl.key, arrayEl.renderFn)`

Comment: I was just about to ask when @Justinas commented: Why are these functions being added later rather than when creating the array in the first place, [like this](https://pastebin.com/n9AJL2CT) (but presumably with functions that aren't identical)?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder because ‘column’ is imported from another file and the components that are added (eg. <Component1 />) contain an OnClick event that calls a function that needs to be define inside my main component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your constraints, I'd probably approach it like this (see comments):

```
// The array you import from another file
const array = [
  {
    key: '1234',
    title: 'Column 1'
  },
  {
    key: '5678',
    title: 'Column 2'
  },
  {
    key: '9101',
    title: 'Column 3'
  }
];

// Your renderers (raw numeric literals are valid, but since your keys are
// strings, I've used strings here)
const renderers = {
    "1234": (props) => <Component1 {...props} />,
    "9101": (props) => <Component1 {...props} />
};

// Map, **copying** rather than modifying the array's objects
const newColumns = array.map(entry => ({
    ...entry,
    render: renderers[entry.key]
}));
```

If you like, you can use a `Map` instead of an object, but if it's a static structure like that I'd probably go ahead and use an object:

```
const renderers = new Map([
    ["1234", (props) => <Component1 {...props} />],
    ["9101", (props) => <Component1 {...props} />]
]);
```

and then

```
const newColumns = array.map(entry => ({
    ...entry,
    render: renderers.get(entry.key)
}));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. An object with key values is what I was looking for.